# How to make multiple columns of independent values into 2 column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

If I have data that looks like this

| Condition 1 | Condition 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 41 |
| 17 | 45 |

where the numeric values are length.

Is there a way to change the data so that it looks like this instead

| Condition | length |
| --- | --- |
| Condition 1 | 11 |
| Condition 1 | 17 |
| Condition 2 | 41 |
| Condition 2 | 45 |

I've looked at transpose, unite, and pivot_longer. But it seemed like it wouldn't give me the results I was looking for. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: If your data is in a data.frame called `dd`, you should be able to do `tidyr::pivot_longer(dd, everything())`. This is just a wide to long transformation.

Answer (score 1):

The base function `stack` is a straightforward way to accomplish this:

```
inp <- read.table(text="Condition_1 | Condition_2 # remove the extraneous "pipes"
  11          | 41 
      17          | 45 " , head=T,sep="|")
stack(inp)
  values         ind
1     11 Condition_1
2     17 Condition_1
3     41 Condition_2
4     45 Condition_2

stack(inp)[2:1]   # swap columns with "["
          ind values
1 Condition_1     11
2 Condition_1     17
3 Condition_2     41
4 Condition_2     45
```

I'm sure that there must be a `pivot_longer` approach that will work as well.